# Node.js error : %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: node.js, bcrypt

Hi I downloaded a copy of my project from a running Node.js server and tried running it but encountered the following error :

Error :

```
E:\Projects\Smart Automation Web\Zigma_copy\automator\node_modules\bcrypt\node_modules\bindings\bindings.js:79
        throw e
              ^
Error: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
E:\Projects\Smart Automation Web\Zigma_copy\automator\node_modules\bcrypt\build\Release\bcrypt_lib.node
    at Error (native)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at bindings (E:\Projects\Smart Automation Web\Zigma_copy\automator\node_modules\bcrypt\node_modules\bindings\bindings.js:74:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Projects\Smart Automation Web\Zigma_copy\automator\node_modules\bcrypt\bcrypt.js:3:35)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Projects\Smart Automation Web\Zigma_copy\automator\api\services\UserManager.js:2:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
```

How I tried to run my application :

1. I downloaded the complete app folder from my server using FTP
2. I opened the project through webstorm IDE
3. I opened its terminal and typed : npm install
4. It was success .
5. Then I typed sails lift and got the following error .

I am a novice and not able to find why it fails . Though I can read the error and it said something about my UserManager.js , so I am atatching that here too .

UserManager.js :

```
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

var jwtSecret = "werisdkf120sdkfr84rwerf";
var ISSUER = "home-automator.com";
var EXPIRY_TIME = 120*500;

function genToken(user) {
  var token = jwt.sign({id: user.id}, jwtSecret, {issuer: ISSUER, expiresInMinutes: EXPIRY_TIME});
  return token;
}

module.exports = {
  hashPassword: function (plainTxtPassword, salt, next) {
    salt = salt || bcrypt.genSaltSync(6);
    bcrypt.hash(plainTxtPassword, salt, function (err, hash) {
      if (err) {
        return next({err: {message: "Something went wrong. Please try again later."}});
      }
      next(null, hash, salt);
    })
  },

  createUser: function (newUser, next) {
    User.findOneByEmail(newUser.email, function (err, user) {
      if (err) {
        return next({err: {message: "Failed to create user. Please try again later."}});
      }

      if (user) {
        return next({err: {message: "Email already registered. Please try a different email address."}})
      }

      User.create(newUser, function (err, user) {
        if (err) {
          return next({err: err});
        }

        next(null, user);
      })
    })
  },

  generateAuthToken: function (user) {
    return genToken(user);
  },

  generateAuthTokenFromPassword: function (username, password, next) {
    User.findOne({email: username}, function (err, user) {
      if (err) {
        return next({err: {message: "Something went wrong, please try again later."}});
      }

      if (!user) {
        return next({err: {message: "Invalid email address and/or password. Please enter valid login credentials and try again."}})
      }

      bcrypt.compare(password, user.encrypted_password, function (err, valid) {
        if (err) {
          return next({err: {message: "Something went wrong, please try again later."}});
        }
        if (!valid) {
          return next({err: {message: "Invalid email address and/or password. Please try again with valid login credentials."}});
        }
        else {
          next(null, user, genToken(user));
        }
      })
    })
  },

  getUserFromAuthToken: function (token, next) {
    jwt.verify(token, jwtSecret, {issuer: ISSUER}, function (err, user) {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }

      User.findOne({id: user.id}, function (err, userData) {
        if (err) next(err);
        return next(null, userData);
      })
    })
  }
}
```

This is what I got after deleting node_modules and doing npm install again . Also now looks some packages are missing because of errors :

```
E:\Projects\Smart Automation Web\Zigma_copy\automator>npm install
npm WARN deprecated jsonwebtoken@4.2.2: Critical vulnerability fix in v5.0.0. See https://auth0.com/blog/2015/03/31/critical-vulnerabilities-in-json-web-token-libraries/
npm WARN deprecated grunt-lib-contrib@0.7.1: DEPRECATED. See readme: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-lib-contrib
npm WARN deprecated jws@2.0.0: Security update: Versions below 3.0.0 are deprecated.
/


> bcrypt@0.8.3 install E:\Projects\Smart Automation Web\Zigma_copy\automator\node_modules\bcrypt
> node-gyp rebuild


E:\Projects\Smart Automation Web\Zigma_copy\automator\node_modules\bcrypt>node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at failNoPython (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:103:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:64:11
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (evalmachine.<anonymous>:99:15)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.3.9600
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd E:\Projects\Smart Automation Web\Zigma_copy\automator\node_modules\bcrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.2
ERR! not ok
-


> sails@0.11.0 preinstall E:\Projects\Smart Automation Web\Zigma_copy\automator\node_modules\sails
> node ./lib/preinstall_npmcheck.js

Sails.js Installation: Checking npm-version successful
\


> kerberos@0.0.7 install E:\Projects\Smart Automation Web\Zigma_copy\automator\node_modules\sails-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\kerberos
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)


E:\Projects\Smart Automation Web\Zigma_copy\automator\node_modules\sails-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\kerberos>node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild
/


> bson@0.2.21 install E:\Projects\Smart Automation Web\Zigma_copy\automator\node_modules\sails-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\bson
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)


E:\Projects\Smart Automation Web\Zigma_copy\automator\node_modules\sails-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\bson>node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild
-


> ws@0.5.0 install E:\Projects\Smart Automation Web\Zigma_copy\automator\node_modules\sails\node_modules\sails-hook-sockets\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

\
E:\Projects\Smart Automation Web\Zigma_copy\automator\node_modules\sails\node_modules\sails-hook-sockets\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws>node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_mo
dules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild
-
> ws@0.4.31 install E:\Projects\Smart Automation Web\Zigma_copy\automator\node_modules\sails\node_modules\sails-hook-sockets\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)


E:\Projects\Smart Automation Web\Zigma_copy\automator\node_modules\sails\node_modules\sails-hook-sockets\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws>node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\
\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.12.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.5.1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! bcrypt@0.8.3 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@0.8.3 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the bcrypt package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls bcrypt
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     E:\Projects\Smart Automation Web\Zigma_copy\automator\npm-debug.log
```

Comment: If you downloaded your complete application folder, it means you also downloaded the `node_modules` folder. As such, `npm install` will report success (of course), but the installed modules, especially the native ones, have been compiled against the target machine. Delete the folder and install dependencies again on your host.

Comment: @RobertRossmann: so you mean , I should delete my node_modules folder for this app and run npm install again in the terminal ?

Comment: Yes. I always recommend recreating `node_modules` from scratch when the application is moved to another operating system.

Comment: @RobertRossmann : Thanks on my way to do it . Though I can see some deprecation warnings and errors . I will soon post the log

Comment: @RobertRossmann : Hi quite a things failed . I have updated the question with terminal log . Can you please check . Also if I need to post debug-log please suggest .

Comment: Read the logs - you are missing Python on your system. For native addons to work (which Sails uses), you will need to make sure *node-gyp* works - check out [these instructions](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp#installation) (*node-gyp* is part of *npm* so you do not have to install it separately, but you must meet its prerequisites).

Comment: @RobertRossmann: Even python is not getting installed . It has other issues for which windows users are crying :(

Comment: @RobertRossmann : Thanks for your guidance . Though I was not able to run on windows version because of python issues . I ran it successfully on Ubuntu machine :)

Answer (score 7):

I had this error trying to deploy on Windows too.

Delete the folder containing npm-bcrypt on the deployment server inside your project folder node_modules (..programs\server\node_modules).

On the deployment server, run:

```
npm install bcrypt
```

And it will re-install bcrypt which should solve that error for you. In addition, you will need Python >2.5 and <3.0 to properly handle fibers. If you install the latest version it likely won't work properly.

Comment: Upgrading to a newer version of bcrypt was for me the solution. After trying Roger K his solution.

Comment: I deleted the folder on the server and run "npm install bcrypt --save" after a build step in DevOps. This didn't work and got bcrypt_lib.node is not a valid Win32 application.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the latest version of Python.

Use the switch --python="C:\Path\To\python.exe"

Set the environment variable PYTHON

Set the npm configuration variable python:

npm config set python "C:\Path\To\python.exe"

Check are ou running behind proxy? If YES, then manage the proxy so that t will allow access to github.com.

Once all the above condition satisfies, then run the below command.

```
npm install bcrypt
```

Answer (score 0):

I suffered a similar issue when I use an `x64` `node.js` on `windows`. It was fine with the `ia32` `node.js`. Solve it by appending `arch=ia32` in `~/.npmrc` at last.